# Count when the value is different then the next one in a particular row

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to make a count when a value in a sequence changes.To elaborate if the next value if the row is the same then counter=0 else it should be equal to 1. I am using R.
for example if my row is below:
[image]

Comment: Please do not use images to show input data.  Instead follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to do this. In base R, we can use `head` and `tail`, to create the `counter`

```
df$counter <- c(0, tail(df$ID, -1) != head(df$ID, -1))
df
#  ID counter
#1 AA       0
#2 AA       0
#3 AB       1
#4 AB       0
#5 AC       1
#6 AC       0
#7 AC       0
#8 AC       0
#9 AC       0
```

In `dplyr`, we can use `lag`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  mutate(counter = +(ID != lag(ID, default = first(ID))))
```

and in `data.table` `shift`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, counter := +(ID != shift(ID, fill = first(ID)))]
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("AA", "AA", "AB", "AB", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `ID` is as shown in a reproducible manner in the Note at the end.

### Case of no duplicate runs

In the question each run has a different value than any other run and if that were the case in general then the 1's are at the positions which are not duplicates except for the first element which is always 0.  No packages are used.

```
replace(!duplicated(ID), 1, 0)
## [1] 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

### General case

**1) rle** More generally, if there can be multiple runs with the same value then use `rle`  and `sequence` to create a vector which equals 1, 2, etc. along each run and look for the 1's.  Finally set the first element to 0.  Again, no packages are used.

```
replace(sequence(rle(c(ID))$lengths) == 1, 1, 0)
## [1] 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

**2) lag.ts** Another approach is to convert to a `ts` object so that we can use `lag.ts`.  No packages are used.

(Note that dplyr overwrites `lag` so be sure it is not loaded -- if it is loaded `detach` it or else use `stats::lag` in place of `lag` to force the  base R `lag`.)

```
c(0, ts(ID) != lag(ts(ID)))
## [1] 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

### Character vs. Factor

All the solutions above work for both the character `ID` shown in the Note at the end as well as a factor `ID` but if we knew that it were `character` then we could optionally use `ID` in place of `c(ID)` in (1) above.

### Note

`ID` in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
ID <- rep(c("AA", "AB", "AC"), c(2, 2, 4))
```